# Excel VBA: Move row to a destination regardless of row count in pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and have very basic knowledge. I have a pivot table which calculates the count of students grouped by enrollment date and columns consists of `Brand Ids`
I want to move a row to the end of the pivot table and the number of rows keeps changing. I tried below code but I can use that only when number of rows in pivot table are constant. Can someone please help me to move row to the end of the table though the number of rows are not constant?

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("StudentCount").PivotSelect "'En_Date'['(blank)']", _
xlDataAndLabel + xlFirstRow, True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("StudentCount").PivotFields("En_Date").PivtoItems( _
"(blank)").Position = 20 
'In current sheet I need to move to 20 but actually 20 is not       constant
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("StudentCOunt").PivotSelect "En_Date", xlButton, True
```

I tried below code as well but it is not working:

```
Dim LS as LONG
LS = ActiveSheet.PivotTable("StudentCount").TableRange2.Rows.Count

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("StudentCount").PivotSelect "'En_Date'['(blank)']", _
xlDataAndLabel + xlFirstRow, True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("StudentCount").PivotFields("En_Date").PivtoItems( _
"(blank)").Position = "& (LS - 1)" 
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("StudentCOunt").PivotSelect "En_Date", xlButton, True
```

**Pivot Table:**

```
Count Of Students
Date        A1   A2   A3   A4   Blank Grand TOtal
blank       69   86   23   45       223
01/01/2014   2   25    3    1       31 
02/01/2014   1    2    5    8       16
Grand Total 71  112   28   51       262
```

Comment: Does sorting the fields not help? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the prompt response. I tried sorting but didn't work because I want the date to be in descending order (Recent to Old date) and blank at the end of table.

Comment: So the blanks have dates as well you mean? Can you somehow show your pivot? like a screen shot?

Comment: Count Of Students
Date        A1 A2  A3 A4 Blank Grand_TOtal
blank       69 86  23 45        223
01/01/2014  2  25  3  1         31
02/01/2014     1   2  5         8
Grand Total 71 112 28 51        262
This is how my pivot table looks like

Comment: Sorry it is not looking in table format after commening. but Data, A1, A2, A3 and A4 are columns. Blank, 01/01/2014 and 02/01/2014 are beginning cells of three rows.

Comment: I edited your question. Is it close to the way your pivot looks like? If not, try editing the question yourself. Below your question there are options, `share|edit|flag`. Just choose `edit`. Also, you can now delete your comments.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for editing. That's how exactly my pivot table looks like.
I want first row(blank date entire row) at the end of the pivot table. Now table has three rows other than grand total but three rows is not constant. Some times it will be 10 o 1 or 20 rows, etc.

Comment: Cool. I'll have to recreate a sample data that will somehow replicate your pivot. Btw, we are talking of a normal pivot here, not Power Pivot right? I'll get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: Thank you for this. Yes, it is normal pivot and not power pivot.

Answer (score 1):

Hi to answer your question, you do not need `VBA` to do this.
The reason your pivot is behaving as such is because your `Dates` are actually not `Dates` but `Dates Entered as Text`.
 See below recreated data:

[image]

Re-entering it as actual `dates` will solve your problem.
So after changing the `Text Dates` to actual `Dates`, your pivot sorts your row as you like.
See below:

[image]

Hope the solution I presented helps you a bit.

**Additional:** If however re-entering all the dates is not convenient, try below code:

```
Dim i As Integer

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("StudentCount").PivotFields("En Date")
    For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
        If .PivotItems(i) = "(blank)" Then .PivotItems(i).Position = .PivotItems.Count
    Next
End With
```

The code above simply iterates through all the `PivotItems`, looks for `(blanks)`.
It then change it's position to the last position which is equal to `.PivotItems.Count`.
Hope this works for you.

Comment: Cool! If you're satisfied with the answer, accept it to earn reputation as well. And also for other users to be inclined answering your future questions. :)